# replace a chained method with a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, methods, salesforce

I have a function from the `simple_salesforce` package,

```
sf = Salesforce(username, pass, key)
```

In order to update an object in the salesforce database, you call sf by:

```
sf.bulk.object.update(data)
```

For example, `account` is the native customer account object in salesforce, so you would feed `data` for updating accounts like this:

```
sf.bulk.account.update(data)
```

I was wondering if there is a way in python to set that specific piece of the chain as an argument.

what I would like to do:

```
def update_sf(object, data):
    sf.bulk.object.update(data)
```

That way I could call:

```
update_sf('account', data)
```

The only other way I can think of doing this is to create a dictionary with the dozens of values for objects in the instance

```
{'account':sf.bulk.account.update(),
 'contact':sf.bulk.contact.update()}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can do `getattr(sf.bulk, object).update(data)`

Comment: wow, awesome. thank you @bro-grammer. One follow up. What If I wanted the `update` portion to also be a variable (change to insert, upsert, delete etc.)..  `getattr(sf.bulk, obj, change)()` wouldn't work would it?

Comment: I think you can do it like `getattr(getattr(sf.bulk, object),operation)`

Comment: wow. blowing my mind right now. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept and close out. thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use builtin function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to fetch your desired entity:

```
>>> getattr(sf.bulk, object).update(data)
```

To also able to dynamically select operation(insert, update, delete) you can chain `getattr`

```
>>> getattr(getattr(sf.bulk, object),operation)
```